# To find files like '-file9' files

Tags: linux

This is Venkat

I was created a file. Name is '-file1'. So how can we open or find these type of files

Thanks,
Venkat.K

Answer (score 2):

```
$ find '.' -regextype sed -regex '-file[0-9]'
```

To find with specific length number like `-file90`, `-file15`

```
$ find '.' -regextype sed -regex '-file[0-9]\{2\}'
```

Or

```
$ find '.' -name '-file*'
```